# Can I enable iOS newsstand features without add app to newsstand?

Tags: ios

Can I enable newsstand features such as auto-renewable subscription and auto download etc without add my app icon to newsstand ? Technically it's no problem to do so but I don't know whether Apple allow it or not. Can anybody advise? Thanks

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. What I want is to support auto-renewable subscription and auto download or maybe the newsstand push notification.But I don't want to show my app in newsstand.Instead, it will still run as a normal app. Is that allowed by Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background downloading can only be done using NKAssetDownload. As of this date I'm pretty sure apple will reject your app if you use NKAssetDownload in an app that is not a newsstand app.